# How to upgrade Python venv version

Tags: python-venv

I installed Python3.10 and I have a venv in a project I have been working on. I don't understand how to upgrade this easily. My background is mostly in Node and JS which is must simpler and more straightforward to change versions.

I was just trying to create a new venv but that didn't work

```
mpaccione@T430:~/Projects/investing/react-flask-app/server$ python3.10 -m venv ~/Projects/investing/react-flask-app/server
Error: Command '['/home/mpaccione/Projects/investing/react-flask-app/server/bin/python3.10', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I also thought maybe I could change the pyvenv config could be changed but that didn't work either

```
home = /usr/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.8
```

to

```
home = /usr/bin/python3.10
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.10
```

Is there just a simply straightforward way to change this? I'm sure it's a common use case!

Comment: I had to sudo apt install python3.10-venv ... apparently venv is specific for the python package and separate.

Answer (score 11):

Locating in the directory with code.
Assuming `~/Projects/investing/react-flask-app/server` for you.

1. Activate *venv* if it isn't (assume, *venv* using for current virtual environment):

   ```
   $ source venv/bin/activate
   ```
2. Save your current dependencies:

   ```
   $ pip freeze > requirements.txt
   ```
3. *Deactivate* current virtual environment:

   ```
   $ deactivate
   ```
4. Delete the current *venv* folder (I don't how it is called in your machine).
5. Create a new *venv* folder (if python3.10 using for Python 3.10):

   ```
   $ python3.10 -m venv venv
   ```
6. Activate *venv*:

   ```
   $ source venv/bin/activate
   ```
7. Install saved dependencies:

   ```
   $ pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```

Comment: When I go to create a new venv i get an error code of exit status 1... yet I know python3.10 is installed and does work when I type python3.10 it runs the python >>>

Answer (score 4):

According to the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) venv has an `--upgrade` command, so if your interpreter-hook of the most current version is `python3.10`, it should be:

```
python3.10 -m venv --upgrade ~/Projects/investing/react-flask-app/server
```

However, it might be that this fails because your hook-alias changed and that the python installation is different from the one used to create the venv. From the docs regarding `--upgrade`:
`Upgrade the environment directory to use this version of Python, assuming Python has been upgraded in-place.`

---

I would recommend to simply store the dependencies in a `requirements.txt` file, delete the venv, and recreate it with the new python version to make a clean new venv:

1. Activate the old venv
2. Store the dependencies in a file with `python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`
3. Delete the old venv folder, keep the requirements file
4. Create a new venv & activate it
5. Install requirements with: `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I still get the same exit error code on the install and in trying to create a new env. I'm quite stuck and already wrote some switch statements in Python which are only supported in 3.10 :|

Comment: In my particular case (migrating an existing `Python 3.10.12` venv to `Python 3.11.4` venv) failed during `python3.11 -m venv --upgrade /srv/homeassistant` with the following error message: ("`Error: Unable to create directory '/srv/homeassistant'`"). The cause of this failure seems to be that in my case `/srv/homeassistant` is set up as a symlink to `/mnt/otherpartition/srv/homeassistant`. Using the actual non-symlinked / resolved path resolved the issue: `python3.11 -m venv --upgrade /mnt/otherpartition/srv/homeassistant` (silently finished after a couple of seconds, with exit status 0).